# Cannot evaluate the trace in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to get a symbolic expression for the trace of a matrix in `sympy`, like this:

```
from sympy import * 
A, B = symbols('A B')
M = Matrix([[A, 0], [0, B]])
t = Trace(M)
print(t)
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Trace(Matrix([
[A, 0],
[0, B]]))
```

Whereas I want an output like `A + B`. I have tried using the `evalf()` function but I get the same output. How do I make the `Trace()` function evaluate the trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trace` represents an unevaluated trace. You can evaluate it with:

```
t.doit()
# out: A + B
```

or you can use the `trace()` method of a matrix to directly compute it:

```
M.trace()
# out: A + B
```